# Find particular solution for DE, not getting the correct answer

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

$\sin(x)\cos(2y)\,dx + \cos(x)\sin(2y)\,dy = 0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

I got that the general family of solutions was $\log|\cos x|=-\frac{1}{2}\log|\cos 2y|+C$

When I put in the initial conditions, I got $C=0$

When I substituted in the $C$ I got $1=\cos^2(x)\cos(2y)$.

The correct answer is $-1=\cos^2(x)\cos(2y)$.

Comment: When you write "where $C=0,$ how does that go with the idea of the "general family of solutions"?

Comment: great thanks for the tip! i have fixed the wording of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log|\cos x|=-\frac{1}{2}\log|\cos 2y|+C\qquad \text{OK}$$
The condition $y(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ implies $C=0$
$$2\log|\cos x|+\log|\cos 2y|=0$$
$$\cos^2(x)\:|\cos(2y)|=1$$
$$\cos^2(x)\cos(2y)=\pm 1$$
The condition $y(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}\quad \to \quad \cos(2y)=-1\quad$ implies : $$\cos^2(x)\cos(2y)=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

The DE can be rearranged into
$$\tan(x)dx=-\tan(2y)dy$$
We can find that the $\tan x$ integral is:
$$\int\tan xdx=\ln C-\ln|\cos x|$$
So therefore:
$$\ln C-\ln|\cos x|=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\cos(2y)|$$
Or
$$\ln C=\ln\left|\cos x\sqrt{\cos(2y)}\right|$$
And so we obtain the equation:
$$\left|\cos x\sqrt{\cos(2y)}\right|=C$$
If we sub in $\{y=\frac{1}{2}\pi,x=0\}$, then we see that:
$$|-1|=C\rightarrow C=1$$
So the full solution is:
$$y=\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\right)$$